# What is com.singularity.util.org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchDog

Tags: java, performance, log4j

During profiling my app I found that 19% of processing time is taken by some FileWatchDog.run() method:

[image]

I understand that this is some piece of log4j, but don't understand why it take so long. What is intention of this method? Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

[FileWatchDog](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/helpers/FileWatchdog.html) is a file watcher module to check if any files have changed and act for the changes accordingly in logging subsystem. Delay of how frequently should `FileWatchDog` be  called is set in the `FileWatchDog` class itself. This is `Apache's` own implementation before `Watch Service API` came in Java 7

Comment: Is there any solution rather than moving to JDK 1.7?